# Python: Filter Dataframe into two separate dataframes

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with columns that look like this:

```
df:
    symbol  json_list                                         date
0   A       [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:1}]    2022-01-01
1   B       [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:0.5... 2022-01-02
2   C       [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:1}]    2022-01-02
```

Note the `json_list` column contains lists of dicts.

What I want to do is separate the DataFrame into two DataFrames. `df1` contains the rows where `json_list` only has one item in the list and `df2` contains the rows where `json_list` only has two or more items in the list.

Therefore, the two DataFrames would look like this:

```
df1:
    symbol  json_list                                         date
0   A       [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:1}]    2022-01-01
1   C       [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:1}]    2022-01-02

df2:
    symbol  json_list                                         date
0   B       [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:0.5... 2022-01-02
```

Is there a Pythonic way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
cond = df.json_list.str.contains('}, {')
df1 = df[~cond]
df2 = df[cond]
```

Comment: Please see the edit. `json_list` is not a string. Is there a way to count the number of dictionaries in a column that contains a list of dictionaries? I tried to convert the column to a string, but then converting it back to a dictionary was really hard. Do you have any idea how to approach this?

Comment: @MathMan99 df.json_list.str.len()

Comment: @MathMan99 if that is the case , would you like accept the answer ?

Comment: can you post your solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try count the `{` count in `json_list` column

```py
c = df['json_list'].str.count('{')
df1 = df[c.eq(1)]
df2 = df[c.eq(2)]
```

```
print(df1)
  symbol                                       json_list        date
0      A  [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:1}]  2022-01-01
2      C  [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:1}]  2022-01-02

print(df2)

  symbol                                          json_list        date
1      B  [{name:S&P500, perc:25, ticker:SPY, weight:0.5...  2022-01-02
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your JSON column since there are no quotes around the strings.

Assuming that you have a properly formatted JSON object stored as a string you should be able to decode it using json.JSONDecoder.decode

In the format it is currently you can get an not very elegant approach by simply doing the following

```
df1=df[df['json_list'].apply(lambda s: s.count('{')) == 1]
df2=df.drop(df1.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options and they all go by counting the occurrences of curly brackets. Either with `str.count`, `str.split` or with regex `re.findall`:

```py
# use the str.split method, looking for the closing curly bracket (or the opening bracket). Since it is a split, it will return always one element more than there are (it is not counting the occurrences)
num_json = df['json_list'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split('}')) -1)
# use re.findall to look for the bracket. This will return the the number of occurrences directly
num_json = df['json_list'].apply(lambda x: len(re.findall('\}', x)))
# count the curly brackets directly
num_json = df['json_list'].apply(lambda x: x.count('}'))

df1 = df[num_json == 1]
df2 = df[num_json > 1]
```

At the end, you can just slice up the table according to your counts